# PHP SOAP element passing

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to pass in values to my WSDL file. The section of the XML file looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="loginEx">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="req" type="ns1:loginExRequest"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="loginExResponse">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="return" type="ns1:loginExResponse"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The loaded xsd file [SessionService?xsd=session.xsd] for login:

```
<xs:complexType name="loginExRequest">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="applicationName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="companyName" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="applicationPassword" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="localPassword" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="version" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="certificate" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

My PHP call is like so:

```
$wsdl = "http://xxxx/axis2/services/SessionService?wsdl";


try {

$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdlsession, array(
    'location' => "http://xxxx/axis2/services/SessionService?wsdl",
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'connection_timeout' => 180
));

$session_param = array("localPassword" => 'password', "companyName" => "Demo Company", "applicationName" => "Demo Application", "applicationPassword" => "password");

$soapClient->LoginEx($session_param);

} catch (SoapFault $e) {

print_r($e);

}
```

The error returned is soapenv:Receiver [detail]

I cant see what I've got wrong within the soapClient. The only thing I can think of is the loginExRequest is not being properly requested?

Appreciate any help!